# Why the name Shelomoth is changed to Shelomith?

Tags: grammar, bible-names

> This Shelomith (**שלמות shelomot**) and his brethren were over all the treasuries of the
> dedicated things which King David and the heads of fathers’ houses,
> the captains over thousands and hundreds, and the captains of the
> army, had dedicated. Some of the [j]spoils won in battles they
> dedicated to maintain the house of the Lord. And all that Samuel the
> seer, Saul the son of Kish, Abner the son of Ner, and Joab the son of
> Zeruiah had dedicated, every dedicated thing, was under the hand of
> Shelomith (**שלמית shelomit**) and his brethren
>
> 1 Chronicles 26:[26](https://biblehub.com/text/1_chronicles/26-26.htm), 27, [28](https://biblehub.com/text/1_chronicles/26-28.htm)

Comment: The spelling of peoples' names were notoriously inconsistent in the OT and NT.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scribal goof, and it's easy to see in the Hebrew.  Here are the two words:

**שׁלמות**  and  **שׁלמית**

See the difference?  In the left-hand word, the second letter from the left is **ו**, but in the right-hand word it's **י**. The upper parts of both are identical; the difference is that the first one is longer.

So at some point when ancient copies were being made, some scribe's stylus/pen for some reason didn't finish the downward stroke, leaving only the upper half.  And the next scribe copying from that copied it as he found it because that was the job of a scribe, to copy exactly what he had in front of him.

Did anyone notice the difference?  Of course they did!  But without knowing which was right -- after all, the mistake might have been that a scribe left his stylus/pen on the parchment too long instead of not long enough -- no scribe would be daring enough to correct the text.  Besides that, the text was regarded as holy regardless of misspellings or lost letters or anything else, so the scribes copied what they had.

Just BTW, there are parts of the Old Testament Hebrew text used by most scholars -- the Masoretic text -- where the mistakes are bad enough that the words are gibberish, making no sense at all as sentences!  In Hebrew class in grad school we were all unhappy with our ability to make sense of a certain chapter and wondered what we were missing -- because we had absorbed that same view of the text, that it had to have been copied correctly.  After a couple of us struggled trying to give a translation of just the first verse our professor told us to not stress because the text was "a mess".

At any rate, there are some arguments scholars could give as to which is correct, "Shlomot" or "Shlomit", and others will point out that it could just as well be "Shlomut":  the ancient text didn't have vowels, and the letter **ו** (waw) often got used to indicate a long "o" sound or a long "u" sound.  But those will most likely just remain scholarly arguments because the Masoretic (and other ancient editions) are set and aren't going to change; it would take publishing an entire new edition to make changes, and that would require lots of scholars coming to common agreement.

I'll also note that in the previous verse to these some ancient texts show one spelling and others show the other one, which doesn't help matters at all.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is what I needed